# MPAndroidChrat - PieChart Not Highlited All Slices

Tags: java, android, mpandroidchart

I'm using MPAndroidChart ver 2.2.3 lib to create PieChart 
and maybe I made somthing wrong but I really not figured it out.
Just the first entry (value) highlighted on touch, and the other slices are not,
What can be the problem?
thanks!

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.alfred.alfredapplication.R;
import com.alfred.alfredapplication.bl.paymentsdb.PaymentsDBManager;
import com.alfred.alfredapplication.bl.secondlevelparse.PaymentsManager;
import com.alfred.alfredapplication.ui.items.PieItem;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.PieChart;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.Entry;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.PieData;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.PieDataSet;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.highlight.Highlight;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.listener.OnChartValueSelectedListener;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.utils.ColorTemplate;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.mail.MessagingException;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Activities that contain this fragment must implement the
 * {@link Home_Companies.OnFragmentInteractionListener} interface
 * to handle interaction events.
 * Use the {@link Home_Companies#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class Home_Companies extends Fragment implements OnChartValueSelectedListener {
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public Home_Companies() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment Home_Companies.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static Home_Companies newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        Home_Companies fragment = new Home_Companies();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_combiend_list, container, false);
        final PieChart mContentView = (PieChart) view.findViewById(R.id.pie_chart_all_home);


        PieItem pieItem = createPieForView(mContentView);

        TextView mTotalTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_total);
        mTotalTextView.setText(String.valueOf(pieItem.totalAmount) + " ILS");

        TextView mLastScanTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_lastscan);

        TextView mUserTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_user);

        TextView mNotesTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_notes);


        //mContentView.getLegend().setEnabled(false);
        //mContentView.animateY(3000, Easing.EasingOption.EaseInOutQuad);

        return view;
    }

    private PieItem createPieForView(final PieChart mContentView) {

        PieItem pieItem = getdata();

        mContentView.setDescription("");
        mContentView.setHoleRadius(80f);
        mContentView.setRotationEnabled(false);
        mContentView.setCenterTextSize(35f);
        mContentView.setUsePercentValues(true);
        mContentView.setTouchEnabled(true);
        mContentView.setClickable(true);
        mContentView.setHovered(true);
        mContentView.setHighlightPerTapEnabled(true);
        mContentView.setDrawSliceText(false);

        mContentView.getLegend().setEnabled(false);

        mContentView.setOnChartValueSelectedListener(this);

        pieItem.entries.add(new Entry(3000, 3));
        pieItem.labels.add("Temp");

        PieDataSet dataset = new PieDataSet(pieItem.entries, "");
        dataset.setSliceSpace(3f);
        dataset.setValueTextSize(12f);
        dataset.setValueTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        //dataset.setHighlightEnabled(true);

        dataset.setColors(ColorTemplate.JOYFUL_COLORS);

        PieData data = new PieData(pieItem.labels, dataset);
        //data.setHighlightEnabled(true);

        mContentView.setData(data);

        mContentView.highlightValues(null);

        mContentView.invalidate();

        return pieItem;

    }

    private PieItem getData() {
        PieItem pieItem = null;
        List<Entry> entries = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> labels = new ArrayList<>();
        float totalAmount = 0;
        PaymentsDBManager paymentsDBManager = new PaymentsDBManager(getContext());
        for (int index = 0; index < PaymentsManager.PaymentsTypes.values().length; index++) {
            String currPayment = PaymentsManager.PaymentsTypes.values()[index].name();
            try {
                BigDecimal bigDecimal = paymentsDBManager.getPaymentTotalAmountByName(currPayment);
                float currAmountPayment = bigDecimal.floatValue();
                if (currAmountPayment != 0) {
                    totalAmount = totalAmount + currAmountPayment;
                    labels.add(currPayment);
                    entries.add(new Entry(currAmountPayment, index));
                }
            } catch (MessagingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        pieItem = new PieItem(entries, "Total", totalAmount, labels);

        return pieItem;
    }

    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onValueSelected(Entry entry, int i, Highlight highlight) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected() {

    }

    /**
     * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
     * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
     * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
     * activity.
     * <p/>
     * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
     * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
     * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
     */
    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }
}
```

Comment: `pieItem.entries.add(new Entry(3000, 3));` don't do this.

Answer (score 0):

When you are creating new entry, give it unique index (starting from 0).